How to update the set of values of an enum partition in Athena
Parquet files are stored in AWS S3 with prefixes like /fruit=.../year=.../month=.../day=.../.
Their data are queried via AWS Athena, with a table in which fruit is typed as an enum:
'projection.fruit.type'='enum',
'projection.fruit.values'='apple,banana,cherry',

Later we could have Parquet files under prefix /fruit=date/year=....
But their data won't be visible from Athena until the projection is updated with apple,banana,cherry,date.
How to keep the Athena partition up to date with the current S3 prefixes?
Ideally in real time, but refreshing it once or twice a day might be an acceptable compromise for now.
The cardinality is not too high, hundreds of values at most.
I've seen that there is a projection type of injected which may be a good fit, but I'm unsure, and I am wondering if there could be any drawbacks.
EDIT: injected is not the solution as it requires the query to provide the values to replace the placeholders in the location template, it won't automatically get them from S3 prefixes.
What is working is updating manually the list via ALTER TABLE goods SET TBLPROPERTIES ('projection.fruit.values', '...') so maybe having a Lambda function collect the values and run this query on a regular basis is an acceptable workaround.

For now I've implemented a manual update of the projections in a Lambda function:
public async Task<Output> FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
{
    var s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
    var athena = new AmazonAthenaClient();

    async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetProjectionValues(string prefix)
    {
        var listPrefixesResponse = await s3.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request
        {
            BucketName = "...",
            Prefix = prefix,
            Delimiter = "/"
        });

        var prefixes = listPrefixesResponse.CommonPrefixes;

        var values = new List<string>();
        foreach (var value in prefixes.Select(p => p.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Split("=")[1]))
        {
            values.Add(value);
        }

        return values;
    }

    async Task UpdateProjectionValues(string table, string projection, string values)
    {
        const string DB = "...";
        var alterQueryResponse = await athena.StartQueryExecutionAsync(new StartQueryExecutionRequest
        {
            QueryString = $"ALTER TABLE {DB}.{table} SET TBLPROPERTIES ('projection.{projection}'='{values}')",
            ResultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration
            {
                OutputLocation = "s3://..."
            }
        });

        var getStatusResponse = await athena.GetQueryExecutionAsync(new GetQueryExecutionRequest
        {
            QueryExecutionId = alterQueryResponse.QueryExecutionId
        });

        var ongoingStatuses = new[] { QueryExecutionState.QUEUED, QueryExecutionState.RUNNING };
        while (ongoingStatuses.Contains(getStatusResponse.QueryExecution.Status.State))
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            getStatusResponse = await athena.GetQueryExecutionAsync(new GetQueryExecutionRequest
            {
                QueryExecutionId = alterQueryResponse.QueryExecutionId
            });
        }

        if (getStatusResponse.QueryExecution.Status.State != QueryExecutionState.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Update of projection {projection} failed: State={getStatusResponse.QueryExecution.Status.State} Reason=\"{getStatusResponse.QueryExecution.Status.StateChangeReason}\".");
        }
    }

    var fruits = await GetProjectionValues($"goods/fruit=");
    await UpdateProjectionValues("goods", "fruit.values", string.Join(",", fruits));

    var currentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
    await UpdateProjectionValues($"goods", "year.range", $"2024,{currentYear}");

    return new(fruits.ToArray(), Enumerable.Range(2024, currentYear - 2024 + 1).ToArray());
}

